# ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `attr_accessible')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In a rails project, I use `inherited_resources 1.5.0 gem`. I have below model:

`forums_controller.rb`:

```
class ForumsController < InheritedResources::Base
  respond_to :json
  skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token
  def permitted_params
    params.permit(vocabulary: [:name])
  end
end
```

`forum.rb`:

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

Now when I want create new forum, I post params to rails project, In this state, I have a problem:

when I use `attr_accessible :name` in my forum model(`forum.rb`), I get below error in server log and forum don't save to database:

```
Started GET "/forums" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-09 11:51:42 +0430

ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method 'attr_accessible' for #<Class:0x000000064c0468>):
  app/models/forum.rb:2:in '<class:Forum>'
  app/models/forum.rb:1:in '<top (required)>'
  app/controllers/forums_controller.rb:3:in '<top (required)>'
```

and when I remove `attr_accessible :name` in my forum model, new forum save to database with `empty name`. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `attr_accessible` is depreciated in Rails 4 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `attr_accessible` from `forum.rb` and change `forums_controller.rb`:

`forums_controller.rb`:

```
class ForumsController < InheritedResources::Base
  respond_to :json

  #replace permitted_params with forum_params
  #the name have to similar to controller name
  def forum_params
    params.require(:forum).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

`forum.rb`:

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  #some validation
end
```